# Are kafka acks received in the same order of produced messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm working on a process that collect data from IBM MQ and process it to a kafka topic.
To make sure not loosing any message,I need to commit my JMS message only after making sure my message is being sent and received by kafka broker.
I don't want to use synchronous kafka producer (waiting on future.get()) because of the performance impact it may have,instead I want to commit my JMS message inside the callback I'm providing my kafka producer.
For this to work correctly, I need the garantee that ack will be received in the same order of my produced messages (first ack corresponds to the first message being sent..).

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: No, they are not guaranteed to be in the same order.

Comment: By default, no, but please share your Kafka producer settings so we can see what settings you might have set that can allow for this.

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer,
I haven't yet started code ready, the question was to identify which approach I can use and if I can rely on kafka producer callbacks for commiting JMS messages correctly.
If there is  a required producer configuration to ensure this, can you please share it?

Answer (score 0):

These are the producer configs you want for ordered Kafka producer messages

```
enable.idempotence=true
acks=all
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=5
retries=2147483647
```

The last two are defaults, so you don't explicitly need to set them.

Details - https://developer.confluent.io/tutorials/message-ordering/kafka.html

However, there will be no guaranteed order of Kafka producer *callbacks* unless you use a synchronous producer

> collect data from IBM MQ and process it to a kafka topic

You can use Kafka Connect for this rather than writing your own producer

Answer (score 0):

We need to talk little about the messages processing guarantee here.

If we are after the exactly-once processing semantics and messaging order, then the consumers must be configured with isolation.level="read_committed" and producers have to be configured with retries=Integer.MAX_VALUE, enable.idempotence=true, and max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1 per default.

Also, setting max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1, will guarantee that messages will be written to the broker in the order in which they were sent, even when retries occur.